# Graying-out of questions in queue?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I notice that sometimes a question in the recent queue is "grayed out." Occasionally it's my question, usually someone else's. If it matters, I use a Mac.

My first guess was that there is some functionality related to spam in play, because I sometimes notice this when I copy something from a Tex file of my own to the editor online. The question is still visible when you click it, but it's hard to read the title in the queue.

Is it a bug? Computer-related idiopathy? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Are they questions with lots of downvotes? Highly downvoted answers are greyed out. Or are they questions with tags that you've marked as a "favorite"? Perhaps you can post a screenshot?

Comment: Posting a screenshot is not possible at the moment, but the questions were not downvoted as far as I know (would I see that if the tally were not negative?), and I haven't knowingly marked any tags as favorites. It does look like functionality that might be associated with a torrent of downvotes or something...

Comment: The greying out I'm thinking of shows up when the *total* is highly negative (I think it kicks in somewhere between a -3 or -5 total). Do you mean the text looks lighter than usual, or do you mean the background to the question is a different color?

Comment: It looks as though someone has overlaid a tranparent white film. No, the total is not negative. Hmm--I notice that when I log out, the problem disappears...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the questions look like the attached picture, then what has happened is you have accidentally set some tags to ignore. In the example, I have set "number-theory" as an ignored tag and the first and fourth questions are faded because they are tagged "number-theory".[image]

Comment: Thanks--I'll check and report back. Your snapshot shows an actual gray. Mine is an obscuring white transparency.

Comment: It doesn't appear gray to me, rather an obscuring white transparency as well.

Comment: Yep, that's it. I would not have deliberately set the account to ignore "number theory" but that's the culprit. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah; since I don't ignore any tags, that's why I couldn't figure out what the trouble was...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Neither do I, so I temporarily ignored the [number-theory] tag.