# Shadow or background question

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, ignored-tags

Why I see sometimes some questions with shadows or in background like the picture in attachment?

[image]
My question, following my comment, refers to the fact that I do not have any **Ignored tags** and, for example, `permutations` and `combinations` they are not into favoritied tags and into ignored tags, like this image:

[image]

**Addendum by last comment:**

[image]

**Updating: I don't know if it's the same problem as before but I see the answer shaded.**

[image]

Comment: Likely it is because you ignore a tag; that sometimes even happens inadvertently.

Comment: @quid Thank you very much for your reply. I have only 9 Watched Tags and for example I have ignored permutations and combinations...but I see normally the question.

Comment: @quid Just I have improved my question and I think that it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I reopened as the answer does not appear to be clear inded;

Comment: @quid Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: No problem for reference I'll add the link which was autodeleted in the process https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/graying-out-of-questions-in-queue

Comment: Just to make sure, can you check [the tag preferences in the settings](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Surely, now I edit my question with a screenshot. Thank you very much.